# Paypal Sandbox does not update even though test payment is successful

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working with the PayPal plus with my php website.
here is the array:

```
[_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
    (
        [intent] => sale
        [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object
            (
                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                    (
                        [payment_method] => paypal
                    )

            )

        [redirect_urls] => PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls Object
            (
                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                    (
                        [return_url] => http://test.localhost/paypal/payment.php?success=true
                        [cancel_url] => http://test.localhost/paypal/payment.php?success=false
                    )

            )

        [transactions] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object
                                    (
                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                            (
                                                [total] => 2.00
                                                [currency] => EUR
                                            )

                                    )

                                [description] => Payment description
                                [invoice_number] => 592c19cbf1ec7
                                [item_list] => PayPal\Api\ItemList Object
                                    (
                                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                            (
                                                [items] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
                                                            (
                                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => Test item 1
                                                                        [price] => 1.00
                                                                        [currency] => EUR
                                                                        [quantity] => 1
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                        [1] => PayPal\Api\Item Object
                                                            (
                                                                [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [name] => Test item 2
                                                                        [price] => 1.00
                                                                        [currency] => EUR
                                                                        [quantity] => 1
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [related_resources] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [id] => PAY-1J0352713K9487458LEWBTTQ
        [state] => created
        [create_time] => 2017-05-29T12:53:34Z
        [links] => Array
            (
                [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1J0352713K9487458LEWBTTQ
                                [rel] => self
                                [method] => GET
                            )

                    )

                [1] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9MG964386B5214149
                                [rel] => approval_url
                                [method] => REDIRECT
                            )

                    )

                [2] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                    (
                        [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array
                            (
                                [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1J0352713K9487458LEWBTTQ/execute
                                [rel] => execute
                                [method] => POST
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

And then the paypal iframe:

```
PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
    "approvalUrl": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9MG964386B5214149",
    "placeholder": "ppplus",
    "country": "DE",
    "mode": "sandbox",
    "buttonLocation": "inside"
})
<div id="ppplus"></div>
```

The sandbox payment shows successfully. But i can't see any update on my sandbox account and my existing amount remain same.
Any one has any clue why it is happening?

Comment: what are the transaction ID return in the response from PayPal?

Comment: Like this:
'paymentId=PAY-5T486996MW6976803LEWDNUY&token=EC-0AU845072E317641H&PayerID=ZV79XJBR4MSXA'